# React Dev Tools setInProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-props

I've been looking at the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/) for React Dev Tools and using some of their code for my own projects.  I'm having trouble understanding what the `path` is supposed to be in the [`setInProps`](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/blob/7062b52f13481f575988135ff33cd53fa7645894/backend/getData.js#L180) method:

```
function setInProps(internalInst, forceUpdate, path: Array<string | number>, value: any) {
  var element = internalInst._currentElement;
  internalInst._currentElement = {
    ...element,
    props: copyWithSet(element.props, path, value),
  };
  forceUpdate.call(internalInst._instance);
}
```

It seems like it is some type of array.  It's passed to `copyWithSet(...)`:

```
function copyWithSet(obj: Object | Array<any>, path: Array<string | number>, value: any): Object | Array<any> {
  return copyWithSetImpl(obj, path, 0, value);
}
```

and then `copyWithSetImpl(...)`:

```
function copyWithSetImpl(obj, path, idx, value) {
  if (idx >= path.length) {
    return value;
  }
  var key = path[idx];
  var updated = Array.isArray(obj) ? obj.slice() : {...obj};
  // $FlowFixMe number or string is fine here
  updated[key] = copyWithSetImpl(obj[key], path, idx + 1, value);
  return updated;
}
```

Can someone please provide an example of how I could use `setInProps` to update something in the props?  I already have the internal instance object and assume that `value` is just the prop value.